# How can I sort sequentially numbered files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have files named as follows:

```
X-1.pdf
X-2.pdf
X-3.pdf
.
.
.
X-15.pdf
```

When ordered based on string value, the sequence is as follows:

```
X-1.pdf
X-10.pdf
X-11.pdf
.
.
.
```

Assuming these files are stored in a string array, how would I order the array so that the files appear in the 'expected' manner ie

```
X-1.pdf
X-2.pdf
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localeCompare` with the `numeric` option set to `true`:

```js
console.log(
  ['X-11.pdf',
    'X-1.pdf',
    'X-9.pdf',
    'X-10.pdf',
    'X-2.pdf',
  ].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {numeric: true }))
)
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than the duplicate answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way would be to remove the alpha characters, and sort that way.

```js
const files = ['X-1.pdf', 'X-10.pdf', 'X-2.pdf', 'X-3.pdf', 'X-4.pdf', 'X-11.pdf', 'X-5.pdf', 'X-6.pdf', 'X-8.pdf', 'X-9.pdf', 'X-12.pdf', 'X-13.pdf', 'X-14.pdf', 'X-15.pdf', 'X-7.pdf']

files.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')) - parseInt(a.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')))

console.log(files)
```